# Can I use "and" between coordinate adjectives?

Tags: coordination

Can I use "and" instead of a comma between coordinate adjectives? If so, which alternative is preferable in formal writing?

> It was a hot, sunny day.

> It was a hot and sunny day.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

You can decide on each occasion which construction make the sentence flow better.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140252/discussion-on-answer-by-prl75-can-i-use-and-between-coordinate-adjectives).

Answer (score 0):

The sentences:

> - It was a hot, sunny day.
> - It was a hot and sunny day.

are both grammatically correct. A native speaker might use either, and would understand either. The choice is a matter of style, there is no significant difference in meaning.

I do not agree with the idea, expressed in a comment to another answer, that one form is more serious, or carries more significance, than the other.

If tre are three or more adjectives being applied to the noun, one may use a mixed form:

> It was a hot, sunny, and humid day.

Or two different conjunctions may be used if both apply. For example:

> It was a hot and sunny, but humid, day.